# "drush up" fails with "pm-updatestatus failed."

Tags: drush, updating

When I execute `drush up`, it returns the following error message.

> The command could not be executed successfully (returned: *The
>   filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect*, code:
>   1)   pm-updatestatus failed.

`drush pm-updatestatus` runs without errors.

Similarly, `"C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\drush\\drush\\drush"
    --backend=2 --verbose --debug --root="C:\\website\\drupal7"
    --uri=http://default  pm-updatestatus 2>&1`, which I extracted from the debug output of `drush -d up` (see below) also successfully runs.

What could I try?

The debug output is the following.

> Calling hook drush_pm_updatecode_validate [11.27 sec, 17.04 MB]
>   Returned from hook drush_pm_updatecode_validate [11.27 sec, 17.04 MB] 
>   Calling hook drush_pm_updatecode [11.27 sec, 17.05 MB]
>   Cache MISS cid: 8.1.2-alias-path--59067c616e8e4f3b7078e0502d77bf35
>   [11.27 sec, 17.06 MB]   Backend invoke:
>   "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\drush"
>   --backend=2 --verbose --debug --root="C:\website\drupal7" --uri=http://default  pm-updatestatus 2>&1 [11.61 sec, 17.09 MB]   "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\drush"
>   --backend=2 --verbose --debug --root="C:\website\drupal7" --uri=http://default  pm-updatestatus 2>&1 [11.61 sec, 17.09 MB]   The command could not be executed successfully (returned: The filename,
>   directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect., code: 1) [11.79
>   sec, 17.09 MB]   pm-updatestatus failed. [11.79 sec, 17.08 MB]

I am using Drush 8.1.2, Drupal 7.50 running on Windows 7, PHP 5.6.23, and Apache 2.4.23.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by editing the file `/path/to/drush/includes/exec.inc` and changing line 331 from

```
return _drush_escapeshellarg_windows($arg, $raw);
```

to

```
return _drush_escapeshellarg_windows($arg, TRUE);
```

as described by peterromero here https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2152

Answer (score 1):

My issue went away when I unlinked my PHP@5.6 and linked PHP@7.2 that MAMP is using. Then I run source ~/.bash_profile (didn't need to reload Terminal).Restarted apache.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting a Drupal error

```
Error: Call to undefined function Drush\UpdateService\simplexml_load_file() in                 Drush\UpdateService\Project::getInstance() (line 74 of phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/vendor/composer/../../lib/
```

which indicated that the php-xml extension was not installed.

```
sudo aptitude install php7.2-xml
```

fixed the problem.